# Why does `narrow-to-region` complain that its args are not `integer-or-marker-p`?

Tags: debugging, functions

I have some functions that depend on `smart-parens` code.

```
(defun outer-paren ()
  "Move point to the  outermost parenthesis."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (while t
      (up-list)))
  (sp-backward-sexp))

(defun func ()
  (let ((start (outer-paren))
    (end (sp-forward-sexp)))
    (narrow-to-region start end)))
```

The above `func` code returns a plist set by `let`:

```
(:beg 145 :end 163 :op "「" :cl "」" :prefix "" :suffix "") (:beg 145 :end 163 :op "「" :cl "」" :prefix "" :suffix "")
```

This causes an error from `narrow-to-region()` when `func` is called.

> (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p (:beg 145 :end 163 :op "「" :cl "」" :prefix "" :suffix ""))

How do I access `start` and `end` as variables within `func`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the values returned by functions `outer-paren` and `sp-forward-sexp`, instead of the positions they move to.

The error message tells you that `narrow-to-region` expects buffer positions - numbers or markers.  So clearly your values of `start` and `end` aren't such.  They aren't numbers or markers because functions `outer-paren` and `sp-forward-sexp` return something other than the position they move to.

Don't confuse the side effect of a Lisp function with its return value.

```lisp
(defun func ()
  (let ((start  (progn (outer-paren) (point)))
        (end    (progn (sp-forward-sexp) (point))))
    (narrow-to-region start end)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to access the property values that narrow to region needs.

```
  (use-package smartparens)
  (defun outer-paren ()
    "Move point to the  outermost parenthesis."
    (interactive)
    (ignore-errors
      (while t
        (up-list)))
    (sp-backward-sexp))

  (defun func ()
    (let ((start (outer-paren))
      (end (sp-forward-sexp)))
      (narrow-to-region (plist-get start :beg ) (plist-get start :end ))))
  (func)
(setq pl '(:beg 121 :end 141))
(plist-get pl :beg)
```